# Variables inside a bash script subshesll

Tags: bash, variables, root, subshell

I am trying to run commands as root and capture the output into a variable. However the variable "loopdev" is returning as empty.

```
sudo bash << "EOF"
whoami
loopdev=`losetup -f --show "${image}"`
echo "####" $loopdev "####"
EOF
```

The normal output for this command would be like below

```
$ image=sdimage.img
$ sudo losetup -f --show "${image}"
/dev/loop0
```

Comment: "<< 'EOF' -> losetup: : failed to set up loop device: Success"   (no loop device was created, not sure why it says success)

Comment: Can u try to set "image" variable value inside the bash script ?  As like below  sudo bash << "EOF"
whoami 
image=sdimage.img
loopdev=`losetup -f --show "${image}"`
echo "####" $loopdev "####"
EOF

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution was to pass in the image variable like this:

```
image=rpi_2.img
sudo image="${image}" bash << 'EOF'
whoami
loopdev=`losetup -f --show "${image}"`
echo "####" $loopdev "####"
EOF
```

Output:

```
root
#### /dev/loop0 ####
```

Answer (score 0):

I tried your problem as like below

```
test=12781278
sudo bash << "EOF"
whoami
loopdev=`echo Hi $test`
echo "####" $loopdev "####"
EOF
```

And the output is

```
#### Hi  ####
```

For your problem, the image variable value is not being passed to the bash shell that you are starting.